# finding solution of $y'=3y^{2/3}$ with $y(0)=0$ with Picard iteration

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been asked to apply uniqueness and existence theorem and search solution with Picard iteration. But I couldnt understand picard part.

The Picard Iteration is given by:

$$\tag 2 \displaystyle  ~~y_{n+1} = y_0 + \int^x_{x_0} f(x, y_n)dx$$

It seems all solutions are equal to $0$. Because substiting $y=0$ to $f(x,y)=3y^{2/3}$ gives $f(x,y)=0$
What can I do from here?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check whether the assumptions of Picard's theorem are fulfilled for your IVP. Note that $y(x)=x^3$ is another solution when $x>0$.

For $x<0$ you have to define what is meant by $y^{2/3}$ when $y<0$.

Comment: is it true and enough to say for  $y_1 = 0$ and  $\forall K > 0 \; \exists y_2 > 0:$  

\begin{equation}
\lvert 3y_1^{2/3} - 3y_2^{2/3} \rvert = 3\lvert y_2 \rvert^{2/3} > K \lvert y_2 \rvert = K \lvert y_1 - y_2 \rvert
\end{equation}

This contradicts Lipschitz continuity so picard iteration cant be used.(?)